# Flutter http Request Error on Localhost http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users

Tags: http, flutter, localhost

Hello Friend i'm new in flutter when i try make http requests on local host i got this error

> E/flutter ( 8392): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 33200
>   **I'm use http pacakge with laravel app on localhost**

```
Future<List<User>> getUsers({int pageNumber = 1}) async {
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users";
    final res = await http.get(url);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      return compute(parseUsers, res.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception("error in fetch userslist data");
    }
  }
}


List<User> parseUsers(String responseBody) {
  final items = jsonDecode(responseBody)["Data"];
  List<User> data = [];
  for (var item in items) {
    data.add(User.fromJson(item));
  }
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to virtualize your local API.

1 - Serve your application on the netmask IP. Supposing are you using Laravel on API, use this command: 
    `php artisan --host 192.168.0.**`

2 - Virtualize your API usging ngrok: 
    `ngrok http 192.18.0.**:8000`